# Facing Issues with Z-Index in react native iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

I have a code written in react native, wherein I want to replace Facebook button with an image, am using Z-Index. I' am able to overlap the image over the FbButton. But the click event of Fbbutton is not working. Below is the source code.

```
  <Image  
              source={require('./images/connect-with-fb.png')} 
              style={[css.innerImage, {zIndex:1000, marginBottom: -50}]} />

              <LoginButton        
                publishPermissions={["publish_actions"]}
                onLoginFinished={
                  (error, result) => {
                    if (error) {
                      console.log("login has error: " + result.error);
                    } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                      console.log("login is cancelled.");
                    } else {
                      AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
                        (data) => {
                          fbAccessToken = data.accessToken.toString();
                          GLOBAL.FACEBOOK_TOKEN = fbAccessToken
                          this.goToHomePage();
                        }
                      )
                    }
                  }
                }                  
              />
```

Please excuse brevity. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried: `<Image pointerEvents={'none'} ... />`? (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#pointerevents)

Comment: Thanks..that worked.